# In the apocalyptic film 'These Final Hours' what happened to Rose’s mom?

Tags: these-final-hours

The film deals with the final 12 hours of the last humans on Earth in Australia. Rose (the little girl that James rescues from thugs) is heading to her aunt’s house where her dad is. But ultimately she only finds her family dead.

Her mom’s body is absent from this. Why is that? Did she abandon her family before the asteroid hit?

Comment: If memory serves, the only time she's referred to or seen is in the scene in the orchard. Rose doesn't say where she is, nor does she express any interest in trying to find her (despite smiling at a picture which contains her image), which implies to me that she probably suicided at the start of the apocalyps or possibly just died (in an unrelated fashion, such as an accident or an illness) when Rose was slightly younger.

Comment: On reflection, that might even be Rose's auntie.

Comment: I have prodded the writer and the producer. Hopefully they'll provide us with a response, although I suspect the answer will be some variant of *"She's already dead and we didn't give it much more thought than that*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, we don't know. We have some clues, but nothing definitive.

- **Her father has a picture of Rose and (we assume) her mother. Rose isn't significantly younger in the photo, which suggests that it was taken in the last couple of years.**

> [image]

- **Rose has fond memories of her mother. It seems reasonable that she would want to be with her, if such a thing was a possibility.**

> I remember this day. It was her birthday. Dad got the waiters to sing 'Happy Birthday' to her. She looked really embarrassed, but I think she secretly liked it.

- **Rose shows no interest in trying to locate her mother.**

With those three facts in mind, I think we can be reasonable sure that her mother is **dead rather than merely missing**, and potentially of something unrelated to the present crisis, although an early suicide could also be an option.